# I cannot hear the difference between front and behind position using 3D sound

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I want to make a real 3D sound effect. I can hear the difference between right and left, but not between in front and behind.

Here is how I set the listener:

```
sf::Listener::setPosition(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
sf::Listener::setDirection(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
```

This is how I set the position of sound:

```
sound.setPosition(0.f, 0.f, -10.f);
```

And then move it the next second.

```
sound.setPosition(0.f, 0.f, 10.f);
```

If I change the X coordinate, I hear the sound shift from left to right, but it doesn't work for Z coordinate.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If there is no difference between back and front, then this is how SFML works. What you can do is you can try to find some setting to reduce source volume if it's behind the listener, or you can do it manually.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good idea. But if I have 2 sounds. One front me far away and second near behind me, I can get same volume, and I don't hear any more difference between front and back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me. The sound is a bit weird on the front.

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    // initialize and play our custom stream
    sf::Music stream;
    stream.openFromFile("music.ogg");

    #define MAX_R 10
    #define PI 3.141592653589793238
    float x = MAX_R, y = 0, z = MAX_R;
    stream.setPosition(x, y, z);
    stream.setVolume(100);
    stream.setMinDistance(5.f);
    stream.setAttenuation(10.f);
    stream.setLoop(true);

    stream.play();

    float angle = 0.f;

    // let it play until it is finished
    while (stream.getStatus() == sf::SoundSource::Playing) {
        sf::sleep(sf::seconds(0.1f));

        x = cos(angle * PI / 180) * MAX_R;
        z = sin(angle * PI / 180) * MAX_R;

        std::cout << x << " " << z << " ";
        if (angle < 90.f)
            std::cout << "1\n";
        else if (angle < 180.f)
            std::cout << "2\n";
        else if (angle < 270.f)
            std::cout << "3\n";
        else
            std::cout << "4\n";

        stream.setPosition(x, y, z);
        angle += 5.f;
        if (angle > 360)
            angle = 0.f;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

References:
[sf::Music Doc](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Music.php)
[Audio Spatialization with SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/audio-spatialization.php)
[Audio Streams](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/audio-streams.php)

Comment: Yea. But still not hear soo much changes.